# PHP Curl request to public API "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: php, curl, post

I try to PHP Curl request. I've got a simple PHP script that sends an HTTP POST request via PHP.

Condition

```
*Endpoint
https://api.rms.rakuten.co.jp/es/2.0/order/getOrder/

*Request
  -Method
    "POST"

*Request Header
  -Authorization
    ESA Base64 (serviceSecret : licenseKey)

*Content-Type
  application json; charset=utf-8

*Request Parameter
  -Parameter Name/Type
    orderNumberList/List <String>
```

My code(php)

```
<?php

  $serviceSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  $licenseKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  $ordernum = "534531-20180618-55345321";

  $authkey = base64_encode($serviceSecret . ":" . $licenseKey);
  $header = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization: ESA {$authkey}"
  );
  $post = array(
      "orderNumberList: {$ordernum}"
  );

  $url = "https://api.test.com/getOrder/";
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  $xml = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  var_dump($xml);
?>
```

But response is only this.

```
string(73) "{"Results": {"errorCode": "ES04-03","message": "Unsupported Media Type"}}"
```

Below is an example Curl code.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.test.com/getOrder/ \
  -H 'Authorization : ESA xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'\
  -H 'Content-Type : application / json; charset = utf-8'\
  -d '{
    "orderNumberList": "543435-20180116-00111801", "524335-20180116-00113801"
}'
```

Any insights or ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$post = array(
      "orderNumberList: {$ordernum}"
  ); `  looks wrong, try `$post = array(
      "orderNumberList" => $ordernum
  );`

Comment: also `{
    "orderNumberList": "543435-20180116-00111801", "524335-20180116-00113801"
}` it is invalid json, likely it should be something like `{
    "orderNumberList": ["543435-20180116-00111801", "524335-20180116-00113801"]`
}

Comment: thanks reply. but I'm sorry, failed.